# Making a heatmap with ArcGIS API for JS while using a Graphics collection as source

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, heat-map

I am trying to make a heatmap from congestion data in the distribution network for electricity. I use a collection of Graphics as the source for a FeatureLayer and add the heatmap accordingly. It all works correctly until I enter the 'field' value, which contains the congestion value. After that, the heatmap just does not color anything that has a ratio bigger than zero. My layer creation looks like this:

```
let hrenderer = new HeatmapRenderer({
            field: "maxpeak",
            colorStops: [
                { color: "rgba(255, 204, 229, 0.1)", ratio: 0 },
                { color: "rgba(230, 184, 215, 0.2)", ratio: 0.1 },
                { color: "rgba(210, 163, 202, 0.2)", ratio: 0.2 },
                { color: "rgba(190, 143, 189, 0.2)", ratio: 0.3 },
                { color: "rgba(170, 122, 176, 0.2)", ratio: 0.4 },
                { color: "rgba(150, 102, 162, 0.2)", ratio: 0.5 },
                { color: "rgba(140, 81, 149, 0.2)", ratio: 0.6 },
                { color: "rgba(130, 61, 136, 0.2)", ratio: 0.7 },
                { color: "rgba(120, 40, 123, 0.2)", ratio: 0.8 },
                { color: "rgba(110, 20, 111, 0.2)", ratio: 0.9 },
                { color: "rgba(102, 0, 102, 0.2)", ratio: 1 },
            ],
            maxPixelIntensity: 250,
            minPixelIntensity: 0,
            blurRadius: 25,
        });

        let belastingLayer = new FeatureLayer({
            title: "Heatmap belasting",
            source: graphics,
            outFields: ["*"],
            objectIdField: "id",
            renderer: hrenderer,
            id: "heatmaplayer",
        });
```

The graphics that are used for the source are created as follows:

```
new Graphic({
                    geometry: pt,
                    symbol: { ...symb, color: symbolColor },
                    popupTemplate: template,
                    attributes: {
                        ...attrs,
                        ...id,
                        highlighted: active ? true : false,
                    },
                })
```

where 'attrs' directly includes the 'maxpeak' value.

I have tried using different field values, using outFields in the layer creation and several other things, but nothing changes that the heatmap shows nothing in the relevant parts.

[image: This is the heatmap when I give the ratio value of 0 a non-transparant color]

Any tips? I'm all out of ideas.